# postgres query not working with time format "2005-06-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC"

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

Schema of my postgres table

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | string |
| created | timestamp without timezone |

Now i am trying to fetch records which were created after a certain time. In my query if I write condition as below , it works flawlessly

```
created > 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000
```

but when i write the below timestamp string, it does not seems to work

```
created > 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

The above is the default format which is obtained when i convert a time.Time object to string in Go. Does postgres not support or understand the latter format?

Comment: No, see the manual for all supported formats. And you can also use to_timestamp() to create a valid format using your own specific input format. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Comment: It could be a POSIX time zone offset: `2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC+0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use time.Time.String() because ["the returned string is meant for debugging."](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.String) There is no reason to expect Go's debugging representation for Time values to match anything Postgres (or any other software, for that matter) understands.

Let the database driver worry about how to encode Time values by using a placeholder in the query and passing the time.Time value as-is:

```golang
var t time.Time = ...

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE created > $1", t)
// Since you're using timestamp without timezone you may want to use t.UTC(), t.Local(), or t.In(location) instead of just t.
```